# Create dotplot in R, with two values (dots) on each y-axis (observation)

Tags: r, graphics

I would like to create a dotplot in R, such that the y-axis is the observations, and the x-axis is the time. I have two time points per observation, and hence, would like two dots per observation, connected by a line, if possible.

I cannot get this to work in R, although I can get one dot per observation:

```
N=10
time1 = runif(N, min=0, max=100)
time2 = runif(N, min=0, max=100)
DF=data.frame(name=letters[1:10],t1=time1,t2=time2)
dotchart(DF$t1,labels=name,cex=.7)
```

If you have any advice, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: What are `A`, `L` and `name`. Please take the time to define all variables.

Comment: Sorry @MrFlick. I got rid of that line; it was irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method using [`ggplot2`](http://ggplot2.org/):

```r
time1 <- runif(N, min=0, max=100)
time2 <- runif(N, min=0, max=100)

DF2 <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:10], 2),
                  time = c(time1, time2))

library(ggplot2)
qplot(data=DF2, x=time, y=name, group=factor(name), geom=c("point", "line"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you; it looks great! Just wondering, how does tgrp variable come into play in the qplot function? I don't see it explicitly called.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - I initially used tgrp (now removed) to allow time1 and time2 observations vary by color. I dropped the call to tgrp after editing the example to create the line between points.